# infinite scroll, when I get to the end, show a link to go to a categories page

Tags: javascript

I'm using isotope and the infinite scroll to display books on a homepage. When then infinite scroll reaches the end, instead of displaying the 'finishedMsg' I want to show a link which will go to another page

here's the js code...

```
infininite_scroll: function() {

    $('#nuggetContainer').infinitescroll({ 

        navSelector  : "#moreTitles", // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
        nextSelector : common.more_books_button,   // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
        itemSelector : ".nugget", // selector for all items you'll retrieve

        loading : {
            img : "/assets/layout/ajax-loader.gif", // gif image for wait
            msgText : "fetching more titles..", // shows while loading
        }

    }, function(newElements) {

        $('#nuggetContainer').isotope('appended', $(newElements), function() {
            common.figure_out_what_books_we_done_got_already();
            nug.nugget_bindings();

            $('#nuggetContainer').infinitescroll('destroy');
            $('#nuggetContainer').data('infinitescroll', null);

            common.infininite_scroll();
        });

    });         
},
```

Comment: If `finishedMsg` can containt HTML, why you don't assign link to another page there?

Comment: finishedMsg vanishes after a few seconds.